# `os.OpenFile` with O_RDONLY hangs on named pipe with no writers

Tags: go, system-calls, named-pipes

I am writing a daemon that is supposed to receive notifications from ephemeral CLI commands and have chosen to do so through a unix named pipe. I have written a short package that on the one hand spawns a separate goroutine to read from the node and send the received notifications down a channel ([playground w/ unit test](https://go.dev/play/p/j6fl48wrZnv)):

```golang
type Writer struct {
    f *os.File
}

func NewWriter(ipc string) (*Writer, error) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(ipc, os.O_WRONLY, 0600)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("writer: open file: %w", err)
    }

    return &Writer{f: f}, nil
}

func (w *Writer) WriteString(str string) (int, error) {
    return w.f.WriteString(fmt.Sprint(str, "\n"))

}

func (w *Writer) Close() error {
    return w.f.Close()
}

type Reader struct {
    f    *os.File
    rmFn func() error
    quit chan struct{}
    done *sync.WaitGroup
}

func NewReader(ipc string) (*Reader, error) {
    err := syscall.Mkfifo(ipc, 0640)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("reader: create fifo: %w", err)
    }

    f, err := os.OpenFile(ipc, os.O_RDONLY, 0640)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("reader: open fifo: %w", err)
    }
    return &Reader{
        f:    f,
        quit: make(chan struct{}),
        done: &sync.WaitGroup{},
        rmFn: func() error {
            return os.Remove(ipc)
        },
    }, nil
}

func (r *Reader) PollRead() <-chan string {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(r.f)
    out := make(chan string)
    r.done.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer r.done.Done()
        for {
            line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error reading from named pipe: %v\n", err)
                return
            }

            nline := string(line)
            nline = strings.TrimRight(nline, "\n")
            select {
            case out <- nline:
            case <-r.quit:
                close(out)
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    return out
}

func (r *Reader) Close() error {
    close(r.quit)
    r.done.Wait()
    err := r.f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error closing named pipe: %v", err)
    }

    err = r.rmFn()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error removing named pipe: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

This does appear to be working, however it suffers from the peculiar behavior that no *readers* can open the file until any *writers* open the file, which appears to be the reverse behavior according to other things I've read on the topic; the usual complaint is that the writers are hanging because there aren't any readers, however, here a reader cannot be instantiated in the first place.

Comment: This is how named pipes work, see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior as documented in the [POSIX system interfaces](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html):

> O_NONBLOCK When opening a FIFO with O_RDONLY or O_WRONLY set: If
> O_NONBLOCK is set, an open() for reading-only shall return without
> delay. An open() for writing-only shall return an error if no process
> currently has the file open for reading.
>
> If O_NONBLOCK is clear, an open() for reading-only shall block the
> calling thread until a thread opens the file for writing. An open()
> for writing-only shall block the calling thread until a thread opens
> the file for reading.
>
> When opening a block special or character special file that supports
> non-blocking opens:
>
> If O_NONBLOCK is set, the open() function shall return without
> blocking for the device to be ready or available. Subsequent behavior
> of the device is device-specific.
>
> If O_NONBLOCK is clear, the open() function shall block the calling
> l> thread until the device is ready or available before returning.
>
> Otherwise, the O_NONBLOCK flag shall not cause an error, but it is
> unspecified whether the file status flags will include the O_NONBLOCK
> flag.

The solution is, therefore, to add the `syscall.O_NONBLOCK` flag to the `OpenFile` call:

```
    f, err := os.OpenFile(ipc, os.O_RDONLY|syscall.O_NONBLOCK, 0640)
```

EDIT: As discussed in the comments, this solution is not portable to `darwin` environments. A more portable solution would be to open the file with `O_RDWR` on the reader side.

Comment: Using `f` is going to fail with the `os.File` api in nonblocking mode. You either need to get the fd and immediately reset that, or use the normal method of opening it `O_RDWR`.

Comment: Not sure I understand why it should fail? and can you explain what do you mean by resetting the file descriptor? This appears to be working fine, see [here](https://go.dev/play/p/ecLkH0MdQMG)

Comment: `File.Read` is a blocking call, and should not return 0 bytes read with no error. Your example does not work, it ends with `error reading from named pipe: EOF`, because `reader.ReadBytes` will return immediately when `Read` does not block and return 0 bytes.

Comment: Even if you refactored this to work by calling `Read` directly, you would be reading in a busy loop which is incredibly inefficient. Open the pipe `O_RDWR` as would be expected with named pipe you want to block on read.

Comment: You can inspect the code again and see that the test passes when you run it. The EOF is caused by the defer statement of the writer which is executed when the test finishes and this is an expected behavior of named pipes (EOF returned when all writers are gone). You can also experiment by adding more writes or commenting out the whole write section and see that the code deadlocks as expected. I created another [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RTMCGr3RGwJ) here to demonstrate the fact that the outer poll read loop isn't tight either (see the prints on each line read).

Comment: I don't understand why you are so insistent on doing it this way, when the answer is well known to just open it `O_RDWR` when you need blocking calls. You are relying on the playground's constrained system to synchronize things. Testing that last example with various timings on darwin will also throw `EOF` and `resource temporarily unavailable` errors before dealocking without any successful reads

Comment: It might be interesting to dig in and see _why_ this appears to work on linux (or at least in the playground). Perhaps the fifo can be dropped into the asynchronous poller on that system where it will use non-blocking io. Regardless though, if you want this to be portable across unix systems, you need start by assuming blocking io is required and let the runtime manage it accordingly.

Comment: Apologies, I am not trying to insist on anything apart from documenting the behavior and its possible resolution(s). I've amended the proposed solution to include your suggestion. My only insistence was to avoid a semantically-wrong situation where a reader has write permissions, that just seems wrong. However, it appears that indeed for the specific case it might be what is needed. Also, for the purpose of IPC (which is what this was originally intended) - unix domain sockets are an even better solution which has eluded me (and it suffers not from these sort of idiosyncrasies).

Comment: I would just be concerned that you are accidentally getting blocking behavior when specifically opening the file in non-blocking mode, and it's not consistent across platforms (i.e. when else isn't it consistent?). These semantics are often somewhat muddled on posix systems, take the file execute bit used for directory traversal, or the sticky bit changing from holding swap space to making owner deletion possible in a shared directory -- there's a lot of legacy in the system and we use it now based on how it evolved.